# Not able to perform cp command using execSync in aws lambda for lo.tar.gz file from /opt to /tmp

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, unix, aws-lambda, amazon-linux

I have a requirement of converting doc files to pdf files, i have followed the instruction given in this link https://github.com/shelfio/libreoffice-lambda-layer and created a layer on aws lambda, node.js-12 runtime.The next step requires me to copy the lo.tar.gz file from /opt to /tmp folder where I would extract it .However when i am trying to run execSync(`cp /opt/lo.tar.gz /tmp/`) its erring out , but cloudwatch logs doesn't show any specific error. When I am  trying to extract  the tar file under same folder(/opt) by running execSync(`tar -xzf lo.tar.gz`).toString('utf8').I am getting following response

```
 "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Command failed: tar -xvf lo.tar.gz\ntar: lo.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory\ntar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now\n",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Command failed: tar -xvf lo.tar.gz",
    "tar: lo.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory",
    "tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now",
    "",
    "    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)",
    "    at execSync (child_process.js:666:15)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:21:13)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
```

I am kind of stuck on this issue for quite some time now, if someone can help that would be really appreciated .

--update : I did a ls under /opt directory and the lo.tar.gz file exists, whta i could figure out is the permissions are different than all other files present under /opt, when i am trying to change permission of the lo.tar.gz file using chmod 755 , it says read only file system error, So Is there any way of changing file permission under /opt directory using lambda.

Comment: Could you do an `ls` just to verify the `lo.tar.gz` file is there under `/opt`?

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks for the quick response,i did a ls and it listed all the files incluiding  lo.tar.gz .
` 2020-05-10T18:17:37.047Z  INFO total 138234
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141550929 Jan 10 14:03 lo.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root        34 Jan 10 15:45 __MACOSX
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        31 May 10 16:09 share
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       207 May 10 16:20 bin `

Comment: Can you try `tar -xvzf /opt/lo.tar.gz`?

Comment: @jellycsc Tried and it still fails